# CHECKSUM oddity/GOTCHA with NVARCHAR and the letter N

Tags: sql, checksum, nvarchar

When I have an NVARCHAR(250) column or Variable containing a value of 'N ' CHECKSUM returns a value of 0. It appears that CHECKSUM is taking the letter N as a reference to convert the trailing space to UNICODE.

A workaround is to alter the datatype to varchar which then ignores the N as a "CAST"
I'm wondering if this is a reportable bug or not ?

```
DECLARE @TestN NVARCHAR(250) = 'N ' 
DECLARE @TestV VARCHAR(250) = 'N ' 

DECLARE @TestN2 NVARCHAR(250) = 'P ' 
DECLARE @TestV2 VARCHAR(250) = 'P ' 


SELECT CHECKSUM(@TestN) AS [ckTest DATATYPE NVARCHAR],
        CHECKSUM(TRIM(@TestN)) AS ckTestTRIM

SELECT CHECKSUM(@TestV) AS [ckTest DATATYPE VARCHAR],
        CHECKSUM(TRIM(@TestV)) AS ckTestTRIMV

SELECT CHECKSUM(@TestN2) AS [ckTest DATATYPE  NVARCHAR P],
        CHECKSUM(TRIM(@TestN2)) AS ckTestTRIM

SELECT CHECKSUM(@TestV2) AS [ckTest DATATYPE VARCHAR P],
        CHECKSUM(TRIM(@TestV2)) AS ckTestTRIMP
```

Comment: Ah, so both `' '` and `'N '` generates the same checksum 0.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: Sorry I didn't state it earlier. Its a SQL SERVER database (On an Azure platform)